# ASP.net Identity 2.0 Sign-out another user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm using asp.net MVC and ASP.net Identity 2.0.

On my website Admin has option to ban user, and I would like when user is banned that he is automatically signed-out from website.

I know that I can sign-out current user by calling

```
AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
```

But is it possible to sign-out another user ? Or maybe shorter his session ? Or anything ?

I know I could make global filter on controllers prohibiting banned users from access but that filter would be ran against each user so I'm not quiet satisfied with that solution.

Comment: You should cache every ban user and then delete his cookie at the filter.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'll need to configure cookie invalidation in Auth.Config.cs:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // important to register UserManager creation delegate. Won't work without it
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(UserManager.Create);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator
                .OnValidateIdentity<UserManager, ApplicationUser, int>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
                    regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
        },
        // other configurations
    });

    // other stuff
}
```

and then update security stamp as Hao Kung says when users are banned.

I've [blogged about this recently](http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/08/cookieauthenticationprovider-and-user-session-invalidation-on-change-of-securitystamp/)

Comment: app.CreatePerOwinContext(UserManager.Create) - do the trick for me. 
I am using autofac, so in my case it looks like this:

  app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<Db>());
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<Security.UserManager<User>>());

Where Db is DbContext
and User is a class that is derived from IdentityUser

Comment: I don't quite understand this. I am using the standard template, so it generates `app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);` which I guess it is the same with `app.CreatePerOwinContext(UserManager.Create);`? It doesn't work in my case :(

Comment: I use identity server 4  skurba but i think there is no such Middelware for .net core 6 and identity server 4 .

Comment: @mahdi this answer is over 8 years old. At that time there was no .net Core, nevermind v6 of it. Of course it does not match your code.

Answer (score 19):

If you use the securitystampvalidator feature, when a user is banned just call: `UpdateSecurityStamp(userId)` to cause any existing login cookies to be invalid the next time they are checked.

[More info about SecurityStamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487322/what-is-asp-net-identitys-iusersecuritystampstoretuser-interface)

Comment: I've added that line of code in my project but user wasn't logged out, can you explain me bit further how should I use it ?

Comment: It doesn't log the user out immediately, there's the validateInterval on the security stamp which you need to configure for how often the cookie is validated.