# How to quickly sign out all the users in an ASP.NET MVC application via Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, logout

While the answer here is fine for one or a couple of users: [ASP.net Identity 2.0 Sign-out another user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878218/asp-net-identity-2-0-sign-out-another-user) it does not really scale, it can take a lot of time: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497517(v=vs.108).aspx

I am thinking about SignalR forcing a refresh on the client and making a temporary change in the routing but not sure this is the right way of doing.

Notes:
- It would be for maintenance purposes.
- I don't want to stop the application, it would be some occasional data synchronization with some other external systems.

Comment: if you're going to sign everyone out, what's the difference between that and stopping the web app, in practical terms?

Comment: @ADyson let's say I want admin users to be still able to log in for maintenance purposes in addition to some synchronization. My purpose here does not really matter. I am more curious in a solution, like is there is a better solution than looping through a lot of users and update the security stamp which from my experience takes really long.
Any routing trick?

Comment: I don't know the size/complexity of this piece of software but iIn larger web applications the admin functionality would be in a separate app and you would be able to leave that switched on, along with any background services if necessary. So you could shut down the user-facing interfaces and services without affecting other parts of the operation. BTW I read about the sign out method you linked to - why would it take a long time? It suggests it should immediately invalidate the cookies if you set the refresh interval to something very short (a few seconds)